# symbols being printed when english alphabet wanted

Tags: python-3.4

I am writing this code and have recently come across an error. I have no idea why this is happening. In theory, the english alphabet should be being printed. However, instead of the english alphabet, symbols are being printed instead.
I can not paste the symbols for some reason, but if you ran the code yourself, you'll understand what I mean.
My full code is posted below.

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
choice = input("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt? [e/d]: ")

if choice == "e":

        message = input("Please insert the message you would like to use: ")
        keyword = input("Please insert the keyword you would like to use: ")    
        ik = len(keyword)
        i = 0
        string = ''

        for A in message:

            message1 = (ord(A)) - 96
            key1 = (ord(keyword[i])) - 96

            addition = message1 + key1            
            string += (chr(addition))

            if i >= ik:
                i = 0
            else:
                i += 1

        print (string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add back the 96 you originally took away :) Alternatively, use the Caesar cipher formula as adding back 96 will still result in symbols appearing (I did the ocr coursework already)

```
addition = message1 + key1 + 96
```

your code will not work if the keyword is shorter than the message, so use the modulo operator (%) on i with the length of the keyword inside the line:

```
key1 = (ord(keyword[i])) - 96
```